# How can I refer to the population of a town keeping the name of the town?

Tags: demonyms

There are words like New Yorkers, Londoners, etc.: *(1)* they keep the name of the city/town; *(2)* they refer to the people living in it. How do I fulfill both conditions for a small town called Somesmalltown? Say,in a sentence like:

> 50% of *Londoners* went to a football match on Tuesday?

Phrases like “citizens of Somesmalltown” or “population of the Somesmalltown” seem to be out of place in this case, as I take it.

Does a phrase like Somesmalltown`s people,Somesmalltown people or similar sound right?

Comment: Does a phrase like Somesmalltown`s people,Somesmalltown people or similar sound right?

Comment: @user48618 Yes they could sound right. The point is that if it's a real place then there may be an accepted word to use, but there's no way of guessing what it is. If it's not a real place then you have lots of options. If you don't want it to seem like you're coining a demonym, you could say something "50% of the people/population of Somesmalltown...".

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous constructions to characterize inhabitants of locales. Often the location name is kept intact, but sometimes there are minor modifications, such as dropping a final *e*, to make the construction easier. Sometimes the change is more dramatic (such as *Liverpudlian*).

Suffixes for inhabitants include

- -er
- -ier
- -eer
- -an
- -ian
- -ite

Which will work for a given locale depends on sound, word structure, and, most imprtantly, the preferences of the local community. Some will resist any neologism for their citizenship.

Comment: Yes, the ones based on Latin are tricker - Oxonian, Cantabrigian, Exonian, Mancunian.